# Ubuntu 20.04 does not see hdmi monitor, Intel drivers only

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, 20.04, intel

I have just upgrade a laptop to 20.04 and I cant get a second monitor to work.

Only Intel hardware.

lshw only shows one display

```
teknopaul@pc:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 530
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:131 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

nothing obvious in dmesg.

everything fine on previous Ubuntu versions with the same hardware, tried a couple of monitors and cables.

```
uname -a
Linux pc 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30
```

kern.log

```
...] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20190822 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
...] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
...] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input31
...] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
...] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
...] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
```

Comment: Can you add some info about your computer hardware?  Is the monitor attached by VGA/HDMI other.  Laptop age and brief spec. Monitor model.  Have you tried other cables?

Comment: Did you have any luck here? I seem to be facing the same problem