# Dual monitor issues with Intel graphical card, after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel

After a dist-upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 on a Dell Inspiron 3662, version 2.12.0, my second monitor connected through an HDMI port is undetected by the OS at start-up, although it sometimes appears after several minutes. (Note that I could use the same two monitors under 18.04, without any problem.) Here are the specs of my graphical card, which may be useful.

```bash
$ hwinfo --gfxcard --short
graphics card:                                                  
                       Intel Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Integrated Graphics Controller

Primary display adapter: #20
```

```bash
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:132 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I feel that the problem should be addressable by upgrading my current drivers for the graphical card, but I'm not quite clear how to proceed. Any help would be great.

Comment: In fact, a very similar question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238416/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-see-hdmi-monitor-intel-drivers-only), but that didn't elicit any solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this was really a matter of **hardware**. The monitor was actually defective, and often produced a flickering screen. Either the transition from 18.04 to 20.04 had made it worse, or it simply coincided with the monitor's deterioration. We will never be entirely sure.

In any case, upgrading to a new monitor solved the problem.